# Running scala spark 1.6 job on spark 2.1 fails

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark job that needs to run nightly.  However, I had to update to spark 2.1 from 1.6.  Now I am receiving an error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.load()Lorg/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame; (loaded from file:/usr/local/src/spark21master/spark-2.1.2-bin-2.7.3/jars/spark-sql_2.11-2.1.2.jar by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@305de464) called from class com.ibm.cit.tennis.ServiceStat$ (loaded from file:/tmp/spark-21-ego-master/work/spark-driver-8073f84b-6c09-4d7d-83f5-2c99527eaa1c/spark-service-stat_2.11-1.0.jar by org.apache.spark.util.MutableURLClassLoader@ee80a89b).

In my SBT my build file, I have the following configs:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
val sparkVersion = "2.1.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % sparkDependencyScope,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % sparkDependencyScope,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion % sparkDependencyScope,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % sparkDependencyScope,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion % sparkDependencyScope,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-repl" % sparkVersion % sparkDependencyScope
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % sparkVersion % sparkDependencyScope
)
```

I am building with Scala 2.11.8 and Java 1.8.0.

Any help would be appreciated,
Aaron.

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchMethodError` exception is a sign of a version mismatch. I suspect you're still trying to use Spark 1.6 to launch your app. It is not clear what is the value of `sparkDependencyScope` in your example. Normally Spark dependencies are specified with `"provided"` scope, i.e. the installed version of the Spark runtime.

`"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided"`

Try running 
`spark-submit --version` to figure out which Spark launcher version is used. If it is not what you expect, make sure Spark 2.1.2 is installed and in PATH.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved.  The libraries were cached in an environment.  After the creation of a new environment, SBT was able to pull the latest sources.

Also, I had to add:

```
 conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")
```